# Move, scale and draw on the same UIImageView

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, uigesturerecognizer

I want to draw on an UIImageView, i use touchesMoved and touchesBegan for this, it works.

I use the pinch recognizer for zooming, it works also.

But how can i move it ? because if i use the pan recognizer it will be in conflict with touchesMoved.

How can i do so the pan recognizer will only be called when the user use 3 fingers ?

I think someone else has already face the issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use touchesMoved with two touches and the users can slide the image with two fingers but just 1 finger will draw... besides it's never a good idea to use 3 fingers anywhere because anyone who has triple-tap-to-zoom enabled in their devices accessibility will not be able to use the 3-finger functions. (I and a lot of my friends have this enabled)

First verify that both touches are on the UIImageView
Then take the x&y values from both touches and average them to get the midpoint in-between your fingers. use this value for panning.
Find the change between the current averaged midpoint and the previous averaged midpoint and apply this change to the images center.

`image.center = CGPointMake(image.center.x+changeInX, image.center.y+changeInY);`

Comment: Yes, it works thanks ! But if i add a pinchGestureRecognizer, touchesMoved will be called too :( How to avoid that ?

Comment: Get rid of touchesMoved and replace it with swipeGesture recognizers... now you can do the single swipe for drawing and double swipe for panning... Apple's API will distinguish between the pinch/pull and the 2-finger-swipe.

Comment: Otherwise you'll have to do alo of math and you won't be able to use the pinchGesture you'd have to make your own.